# Postman - How to get the parameters and values ​passed in the url (Query Params) for validation?

Tags: postman, postman-testcase

I need to get the parameters and values ​​passed in the url (Query Params) to validate these values.

The parameter and value are passed like this in the url:

/Data?value=4

Answer (score 2):

```
console.log(pm.request.toJSON().url.query)
```

you can as query parameter like this in the test script